# For windows 10 Neither ANDROID_HOME nor ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable was exported

Tags: windows-10, appium, android-sdk-2.3

I have already set and verify the environment variables in **windows 10**.i didn't find any solution for this .although there are many solutions but all are for Mac not for windows.When ever i start the appium session it through the error " **An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Neither ANDROID_HOME nor ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable was exported. Read https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables for more details**" [Environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCgX1.jpg)

Comment: Heya, did you maybe manage to solve the problem?